# MVC 5 - What model use to create user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity

I need to have entity `User` for database that will be connected to some other entities like `Job` or 'Sport'  (one-to-many). `User` must have just `id, email, password, dateCreated`, nothing special.

In MVC 5 project in `Register` Action i can create `asp identity user`.

So question : Do i need to add my custom entity `User` or can I use `ApplicationUser` model that are already in MVC 5 project?

What case is usual and what is bad?

Thansk.

Comment: If you want your `User` be able to register and login you shoud use `ApplicationUser`. In another cases use custom model

Comment: @py3r3str, and in case i want my `User` be able to register and logic, but also work like with just entity, to show all users on page, etc.?

Comment: You can use `ApplicationUser` to show all users. It is still 'normal' entity.

Comment: this post can help you http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customize-users-profile-in-aspnet.html